# SED: Match one line and append to end

Tags: string, sed

I want to edit the /etc/init.d/syslog file (busy box type on embedded system).

I need to find the ONE line that contains the string `$REMOTE"` (with ending double quote), and append a string to this line, but before the ending double quote.

Here is the whole string:

```
SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -R $REMOTE"
```

I want to append `-R 172.17.xx.xxx` to this line then end the line with the appropriate double quote like this:

```
SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -R $REMOTE -R 172.17.xx.xxx"
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i -e "/$REMOTE\"$/s/\"$/ -R 172.17.87.6\"/" init.d/syslog
```

... but it appends the new string to other lines without the `$REMOTE` keyword. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enclosing the script in double quotes you're asking the shell to expand variables so when it sees:

```
sed -i -e "/$REMOTE...
```

it expands `$REMOTE` to, presumably, the null string. So just don't do that:

```
$ sed 's/\($REMOTE\)\"$/\1 -R 172.17.87.6"/' file
SYSLOG_ARGS="$SYSLOG_ARGS -R $REMOTE -R 172.17.87.6"
```

Always use single quotes around scripts and strings unless you NEED double quotes to let a variable expand or for some other reason, and always use quotes period unless you NEED to not use them to allow word splitting, globbing expansion etc.

Comment: Thank You, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

`$` has special meaning in regex, it means the end of a line. You should escape it, or using character class:

```
sed '/[$]REMOTE"/s/$/your replacement/' file
```

Comment: While true in general, that isn't why the OPs code is failing and your particular code would work just fine without escaping the `$`.